# How to cite an image from wiki legally?

Tags: copyright

this image is being tagged "CC BY-SA 3.0" on wiki.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iris_setosa#/media/File:Kosaciec_szczecinkowaty_Iris_setosa.jpg

I want to cite this image as a figure in my book that will be published.

How to do this legally?

[CC BY-SA 3.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/) requires this license term

> ShareAlike — If you remix, transform, or build upon the material, you must distribute your contributions under the same license as the original.

some paragraphs in my book is build upon that image, do I need to distribute those paragraphs under CC BY-SA 3.0?

Comment: Did you read the terms of the [CC BY-SA 3.0 license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/)? Which part did you not understand? Note that they don't specify a 'format' per se in which you must attribute them. Normally the citation format (e.g. where to place the name(s) of the authors, the years of publication, the use of periods and commas, etc.) is an academic requirement or publishing requirement of a style guide. It has nothing to do with legality.

Comment: @Brandin Thanks for your reminder. I've updated the post.

Comment: Are you sure you build upon the image? If you show a photo of a flower, for example, and then you write a paragraph about that flower, then to me this is not building upon the image. If you use the photo of the flower and modify it, adding things to the photo, that is building upon the image.

Comment: I just need to write some paragraphs about that flower without remixing or transforming, I am not sure if it is called "build upon". your answer clarify this. Please move your comments to answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: What style of are you using for your written works cited (MLA?  APA? ect.).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because points of citation style not specified in contracts or law are not about the law or legal process.